# MenuBar to top of the app

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm quite new to JavaFX and I have two methods - one returning a grid layout and the other one returning a HBox with a MenuBar, but fot the life of me I can't make it, so it's not overlapping (I want the grid to be a few pixels lower). I have this code in my start method:

```
final Group rootGroup = new Group();
final Scene scene = new Scene(rootGroup);    

rootGroup.getChildren().add(addBar(stage.widthProperty()));    
rootGroup.getChildren().add(addGridPane());    

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use another Layout Manager as root. For example:

```
final VBox rootGroup = new Vbox();
```

Then all its children will be aligned vertically.

Comment: HBox didn't actually work, but I tried FlowPane and it worked like a charm. Thanks!